# Using value stored in variable to update an object property

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript variable, call it temp, that is holding value input by a user. For example,

```
const temp=10
```

I want to update an object property to this variable value.

For example, I want to change

```
var data = [
    {
       
        "1": "1.5",
        "2": "2",
        "subject_input": "null",
        "entry": 1
    }
]
```

to

```
var data = [
    {
       
        "1": "1.5",
        "2": "2",
        "subject_input": value of the javascript variable 'temp',
        "entry": 1
    }
]
```

I've tried just including the variable like this:

```
var data = [
    {
       
        "1": "1.5",
        "2": "2",
        "subject_input": "temp",
        "entry": 1
    }
]
```

and this

```
var data = [
    {
       
        "1": "1.5",
        "2": "2",
        "subject_input": temp,
        "entry": 1
    }
]
```

and neither worked. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{"1":"1.5","2":"2","subject_input":"null","entry":1}]

const temp = "temp data";

data = data.map(o => ({...o, subject_input: temp}));

console.log(data);

//or directly assigning temp to subject_input
var data2 = [
  {
    "1":"1.5",
     "2":"2",
     "subject_input":temp,
     "entry":1
    }
 ];
console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Got it working. Thanks!